# Can i run 86x bit dll in anyCPU without problem .net vs 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, desktop-application

I have dll working with 86bit applications , so when i build my application to anycpu it is crushing i need my target to be any cpu because it solved me some other issues , so the deadlock is that i need is .dll not crushing in target: AnyCpu.(consider that i am working with vs 2008.)

Thanks for helping in advance.

Error:**An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)**

Comment: Nah you're stuck. Whatever problem you encounter when targeting x86 directly means your app have some 64 bit dependency. You'll need a surrogate process https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/ that load the x86 library and expose it for access by the 64 bit process

Comment: When you target the x86 platform, your project will built to a 32-bit assembly that will run in a 32-bit process on all platforms that support it, which includes 64-bit Windows for consumers. When you target the x64 platform, your project will build to a 64-bit assembly that will run in a 64-bit process on all platforms that support it, which does not include 32-bit Windows. When you target the Any CPU platform, I don't think that VS 2008 has a *Prefer 32-bit* box. In that case, your assembly will run in a 64-bit process by default or in a 32-bit process if it must.

Comment: That means that an application that targets Any CPU and is run on 64-bit Windows will run in a 64-bit process. As such, all libraries must also run in a 64-bit process, so they must target x64 or Any CPU.